# Does this special case of Rayleigh's monotonicity principle hold true for the norms of complex impedances?

Tags: resistors, impedance

Take a dipole made up of a set of nodes (i.e. resistors) \$R_1,R_2\ldots,R_n\$ that are connected by vertices (i.e. wires) in any given way. Rayleigh's monotonicity law states that the effective resistance of the dipole, \$R_\mathrm{eq}\$, is an increasing function of each of its variables \$R_1,...,R_n\$; that is to say that increasing any \$R_i\$ will amount to an increase in the effective resistance \$R_\mathrm{eq}\$.

A consequence of this principle is that adding an extra vertex (i.e. a length of wire) within the dipole will always reduce the effective resistance. Indeed, we may consider that the absence of a length of wire is equivalent to the presence of a resistor with infinite resistance. So adding a vertex is equivalent to reducing its resistance from \$\infty \ \Omega\$ to \$0 \ \Omega\$. Hence we may apply Rayleigh's monotonicity principle.

I was wondering if this can be generalised to the norms of complex impedances. That is to say, does adding a vertex within the dipole always reduce the norm of the impedance of the dipole?

Answer (score 0):

Trying your claim on the simple counter-example below

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQHCwG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

proves itself untrue.

Unfortunately that's enough to wipe out the generalization you were after